# Добавить внешнюю библиотеку в проект в IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea, framework

Как добавить библиотеку [dropwizard](http://www.dropwizard.io/) в мой проект? Пользуюсь intelliJ IDEA,если данная информация нужна.

Comment: какой системой сборки пользуетесь?

Comment: intelliJ IDEA .

Comment: тогда изучите maven или gradle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это будет очень сложно сделать в вашей текущей конфигурации. Поэтому стоит поступить иначе - Создать Maven проект.

Создание maven проекта

1. **File** -> **New** -> **Project**...
2. Выбираете **Maven** -> **Create from archetype**
3. Нажимаете **Add Archetype**

   - **GroupId** - io.dropwizard.archetypes
   - **ArtifactId** - java-simple
   - **Version** - 0.9.1
     [image: добавление archetype]
4. Нажимаете **Ok**
5. В списке выбираете добавленный archetype
6. Нажимаете **Next**. Вводите:

   - **GroupId** - ваш GroupId, например *learning* (прочитать можно на тут [Maven Coordinates](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Maven_Coordinates))
   - **ArtifactId** - ваш ArtifactId, например *dropwizard* (прочитать можно на тут [Maven Coordinates](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Maven_Coordinates))
   - **Version** - можно оставить предложенную
7. Нажимаете **Next**
8. Нажимает **+**. Вводите:

   - **Name** - *name*
   - **Value** - название вашего проекта, например *DropwizardSample* (это часть имени класса, так что без пробелов)
     [image: добавление параметра]
9. Нажимаете **Ok**
10. Нажимаете **Next**
11. Выбираете имя проекту и куда его сохранить и нажимаете **Finish**.
12. После успешного создания проекта появится такой диалог. Выбирайте **Enable Auto-Import**
    [image: диалог об импортировании]

После этого запускать проект можно используя вкладку **Maven Projects**.